# iOS 13 beta UITableViewCell Child View Touch Selects Table View Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uitouch

So I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` which has its own custom child view.

[image]

In iOS 12, above custom child view could be touched, it would not select the whole Table View Cell.

**In iOS 13 Beta, touching custom child view also highlights/selects the whole Table View Cell.**

```
    final class myTableView: UITableViewController {
      .......
        override final func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
      {

        //Do things for table view cell selection

      }
      .......
    }


    final class CustomChildView : UIView {
     ........
      override final func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
      {
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
            //Do touch down things

      }
     ........
    }
```

Is there a way to cancel table view cell selection when the custom child is touched?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the ***`view`*** is automatically passing the selection to the ***`parent`*** as well.
What you need to do is override the `setSelected` function of the ***`child custom view`*** so that it would not propagate the selection to the upper nodes of the ***`UI`*** tree.

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Add here code to not select parent
}
```

In Reinder's [Blog](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/), you have 6 different methods (some of them well known design patterns) of passing data between ***`view controllers`***, including working with ***`properties`***, ***`segues`*** and ***`NSNotificationCenter`***

Comment: Is it possible to refer to parent table view from the subclassed 'child custom view'?

Comment: @Gizmodo Please check this out: https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Comment: I changed the custom child view from UIView to UIButton.  Now it works as intended.  I guess UIButton somehow stops touches from progressing up the tree somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final class CustomChildView : UIButton {
 ........
  override final func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
  {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        //Do touch down things

  }
 ........
}
```

Changed UIView to UIButton, and now it works as intended.